# trying to place a text box besides a label in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, label, textinput

i am trying to make a simple form but when i place a textInput box after a Label it comes in the next line..how do i make the text input box be placed besides the Label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mx:Form>
        <mx:FormItem label="Name : ">
        <mx:TextInput />
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

Hey u can use this also, otherwise use Canvas and place item in that using left and right proprtites

like

```
<canvas>
    <Label left="0"/>
    <textinput right="0"/>
</canvas>
```

and Yes finally the `<hbbox>` is the ultimate solution, but putting various tags on a page is bit cuimbersome, so try using canvases as it's a light weight conatiner, and when devbeloping some form, so use `<form>` tag

I hope it will be of some help
tc

Answer (score 1):

You can always use an `<mx:HBox></mx:HBox>` to do what you are trying..

```
<mx:HBox>
    <mx:TextInput />
    <mx:Label />
</mx:HBox>
```

Comment: oh thnx..how dint i think abt it?